# MVC - Bootstrap autocomplete Typeahead

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I want to create autocomplete in my MVC site on a textbox with bootstrap typeahead but its not working.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address.Name)

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address.Name)


// AUTOCOMLETE
        $("#Address_Name").typeahead({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/Places",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { term: request },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { label: item.Name + ' - ' + item.Address, value: item.Name };
                        }))

                    }
                })
            },
            messages: {
                noResults: "", results: ""
            }
        });
```

In the Controller:

```
// AUTOCOMPLETE - Places
    public ActionResult Places(string term)
    {
        var result = (from r in unitOfWork.AddressRepository.Get()
                         where r.Name.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower())
                      select new { r.Name, Address = r.Street }).Distinct();

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

In the `Controller` if I put a breakpoint I see in the `String` term what I wrote to the textbox and the result contains all of the found elements.

When I print the 'data' in the 'Success' section, the message is:

> [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object]

Comment: Try `console.log` your data

Comment: In the console I can expand the objects and I see the object has Name and Address value what is needed for me.

And I see one error too now
In the bootstrap-typeahead.js, here:

Comment: matcher: function (item) {
        alert(item)
        return ~item.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.toLowerCase())

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: undefinied is not a function

Comment: that means your server side is okay. Try checking the response function is in the correct scope

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that exactly. What you mean ?

Comment: I can alert in the response scope the item.Name and item.Address and works, I see the values. But not shows on the UI.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43582844/typeahead-js-for-mvc-5-models/43600940#43600940

Answer (score 1):

You can create simple HTML5 Autocomplete in Boostrap like this

**HTML**

```
<label class="label">Input with autocomlete</label>
       <label class="input">
                        <input type="text" list="list">
                        <datalist id="list">
                            <option value="Alexandra"></option>
                            <option value="Alice"></option>
                            <option value="Anastasia"></option>
                            <option value="Avelina"></option>
                        </datalist>
        </label>
```