# Typeahead.js for MVC 5 Models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, typeahead.js

Ive just imlemented typeahead functionality using thw Typeahead.js for MVC 5 Models wrapper

http://timdwilson.github.io/typeahead-mvc-model/

it all works ok but i just cant figure out how to set the limit on the number of items displayed in the suggestion drop down.  the javascript would be this

```
$('#scrollable-dropdown-menu .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
  name: 'countries',
  limit: 10, -----> limit set here
  source: countries
});
```

but I cant see how the mvc models wrapper implements this, there are three overloads and one of the has 'AdditionalViewdata' maybe this is whats needed ? There is no documentation that I can find and no one else seems to have done this (it looks like it defaults to 5 in the dropdown)  My backend mechanism IS returning more than 5 results, its just not being reflected in the html

```
@Html.AutocompleteFor(model => model.Organisation.Org, model => model.Organisation.ORGID, "Autocomplete", "Organisation", false, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

can anyone help ?

Comment: sorry but I dont understand what your trying to say, I did mention that my backend code was working perfectly fine, its returning a bunch of data items that starts with the chracters ive typed in (starts after the firts 2 have been typed).  so for example, my backend code returns 22 results but only 5 are being generated in the HTML.  So ive assumed theres a 'default' limit set somewhere of 5.  My problem is, how do i change that limoit using the typeahed mvc helper ?  i couldnt see any obvious mechanism

Comment: Okay.  I ran the code below and added 16 return values, and when I typed in the autocomplete 16 values were returned.  So, if you are pulling back 22 records -meet criteria- then 22 autocompletes will be presented.

Comment: thats strange because im only getting 5, Ive checked the returned data in my controller and I am getting 22 data items

Comment: why don't you start from scratch and do my example to see that it is working?

Comment: my serverside code is basically the same as yours, its returning data but that data is not being reflected in the html generated by the wrapper.  Ill knock up something the same as yours and give it a go, but I cant see it making a difference, to me it looks like a limit set in the clientside code.  It should be possible to override the limit set but I cant se how in the mvc part

Answer (score 0):

The key is to use the linq "Take"

This works: 1) Create an action in your controller and set the RouteConfig to start this action

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index20()
    {
        MyViewModel m = new MyViewModel();
        return View(m);
    }
```

Create a view without any type of master page
Add this view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string SourceCaseNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Go to Manage Nuget Packages or PM Console and add to MVC 5 project - Typeahead.js for MVC 5 Models by Tim Wilson
Change the namespace for the added HtmlHelpers.cs to System.Web.Mvc.Html and rebuild
Add this class:

```
public class CasesNorm
{
    public string SCN { get; set; }
}
```

Add these methods to your controller:

```
private List<Autocomplete> _AutocompleteSourceCaseNumber(string query)
    {
        List<Autocomplete> sourceCaseNumbers = new List<Autocomplete>();
        try
        {
            //You will goto your Database for CasesNorm, but if will doit shorthand here

            //var results = db.CasesNorms.Where(p => p.SourceCaseNumber.Contains(query)).
            //    GroupBy(item => new { SCN = item.SourceCaseNumber }).
            //    Select(group => new { SCN = group.Key.SCN }).
            //    OrderBy(item => item.SCN).
            //    Take(10).ToList();   //take 10 is important

            CasesNorm c1 = new CasesNorm { SCN = "11111111"};
            CasesNorm c2 = new CasesNorm { SCN = "22222222"};
            IList<CasesNorm> aList = new List<CasesNorm>();
            aList.Add(c1);
            aList.Add(c2);
            var results = aList;

            foreach (var r in results)
            {
                // create objects
                Autocomplete sourceCaseNumber = new Autocomplete();

                sourceCaseNumber.Name = string.Format("{0}", r.SCN);
                sourceCaseNumber.Id = Int32.Parse(r.SCN);
                sourceCaseNumbers.Add(sourceCaseNumber);
            }
        }
        catch (EntityCommandExecutionException eceex)
        {
            if (eceex.InnerException != null)
            {
                throw eceex.InnerException;
            }
            throw;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        return sourceCaseNumbers;
    }

    public ActionResult AutocompleteSourceCaseNumber(string query)
    {
        return Json(_AutocompleteSourceCaseNumber(query), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

     throw;
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
    return sourceCaseNumbers;
}

public ActionResult AutocompleteSourceCaseNumber(string query)
{
    return Json(_AutocompleteSourceCaseNumber(query), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

credit goes to http://timdwilson.github.io/typeahead-mvc-model/

Comment: has anyone else got any suggestions for this problem ? my serverside code is working perfectly, for example, I type 'fr' into the contole and i get three results, yet only 2 show up in the list clientside.  Im noe faced with the prospect of finding a completely new way to implement autocomplete because this just doesnt work