# Combine uib-typeahead + dropdown[Bootstrap 4]

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap

Combine uib-typeahead + dropdown[Bootstrap 4]

```
<div class="input-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.selectedUser"
       uib-typeahead="user as user.fullname for user in vm.users | filter:$viewValue"
       typeahead-on-select='vm.onSelectUser($item, $model, $label)'
       typeahead-editable="false"/>
<div class='dropdown input-group-append'>
    <button class='btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle' type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span class='caret'></span>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <div ng-repeat='user in vm.users'>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href ng-click='vm.onSelectUser(user)'>{{user.fullname}}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently, I'm getting like below

[image: sample picture here]

I need only one dropdown when I tried to select/type-ahead.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can follow this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43582844/typeahead-js-for-mvc-5-models/43600940#43600940

Answer (score -1):

You don't need the ng-repeat inside the dropdown-menu, as the urb-typeahead is already going to call vm.onSelectUser method.

If what you want is to trigger the dropdown when clicking on the arrow on the right, you can change the dropdown element's class with Angular or jQuery, and make it visible. The dropdown element would be something like the one below:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu ng-isolate-scope" ng-show="isOpen() && !moveInProgress" ng-style="{top: position().top+'px', left: position().left+'px'}" role="listbox" aria-hidden="false" uib-typeahead-popup="" id="typeahead-83-4479" matches="matches" active="activeIdx" select="select(activeIdx, evt)" move-in-progress="moveInProgress" query="query" position="position" assign-is-open="assignIsOpen(isOpen)" debounce="debounceUpdate" template-url="customTemplate.html" style="top: 34px; left: 0px;">
```

(This is taken from the uib-typeahead example on github)